Possible to set fixed seed in MS Copilot?
I have a set of over 300 documents each containing narrative text, and I want to use Copilot to count the number of different "ideas" in each document. However, it's important that the ideas are counted in the same way in each document, so I was wondering if there's a way to set a fixed seed for the whole set. I can't find anything relevant in the MS help online, but maybe I'm using the wrong words to search. Can anyone help?

Sounds like it's an use-case for simple caching, not for fixed seed. Consider extracting "ideas" from these documents beforehand, store them somewhere (database?) and then pull ideas from database, rather than sending it to AI every time.

Thanks for the comment. This would be a great solution if the docs were more similar to each other, but there's not a set list of possible "ideas" that would apply across all docs so I couldn't extract ideas from a subset and use that list to count ideas in the remainder. Once the ideas are extracted from all docs, the task is finished so all I really want is to ensure consistency in the way the ideas are counted across docs.
